# Why is my mapping returning too many entries?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to map an array of dates. Each one of these dates belongs to a group of dates (format array).

So let's say:
Format array is: `let format = [3, 3, 1, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 13, 10, 3, 5, 5, 2, 2, 10];`

That means the first three dates of the dates array are a group of dates, the next 3; the next one is a single date, the next 5... etc.

So my expecting output would be 16 items (same as format length).
The output should be, for example:
The first group of dates:
Start: lowest date of that group
End: highest date of that group

But my output is returning the same entries of date length.

```js
let format = [3, 3, 1, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 13, 10, 3, 5, 5, 2, 2, 10];
let dates = [
  "2021-10-04T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-05T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-06T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-13T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-14T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-15T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-15T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-17T22:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-18T22:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-19T22:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-20T22:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-21T22:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-17T22:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-18T22:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-19T22:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-20T22:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-19T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-20T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-21T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-22T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-19T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-20T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-21T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-25T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-26T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-27T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-28T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-29T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-25T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-26T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-27T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-28T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-29T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-01T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-02T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-03T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-04T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-05T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-08T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-09T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-10T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-01T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-02T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-03T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-04T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-05T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-08T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-09T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-10T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-11T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-12T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-11T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-12T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-13T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-15T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-16T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-17T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-18T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-19T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-16T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-17T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-18T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-19T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-20T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-23T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-24T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-23T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-24T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2022-01-05T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2022-01-06T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2022-01-07T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2022-01-10T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2022-01-11T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2022-01-12T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2022-01-13T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2022-01-14T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2022-01-17T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2022-01-18T04:00:00.000Z"
];

var numTimesUsed = 0;
var nameIndex = 0;
let app_multiple = dates.map(function combineTitleData(dataItem, index) {
  if (format[nameIndex] == numTimesUsed) {
    nameIndex++;
    numTimesUsed = 0;
  }
  numTimesUsed++;
  let end = new Date(dates[nameIndex]);
  end.setDate(end.getDate() + parseInt(format[nameIndex]) - 1);
  return {
    start: dates[nameIndex],
    end: end
  };
});
//
console.log(app_multiple);
```

Thanks

Comment: If you call `.map()` on `dates` you will end up with an array with `dates.length` elements. That's just how `.map()` works...

Comment: `dates.map` will always return an array whose size is equal to `dates` size. You should probably use `format.map` and use `dates.slice`.

Comment: @mplungjan If you make such an assumption you should also explain "why" something might be _"better"_ and in what way.

Comment: because slice needs  an index to be kept to advance the cursor, splice will chop the array for you

Comment: I agree with @mplungjan, `splice` is better. It's more straightforward than `slice`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) will get the groups

```
const res = format.map(num => dates.splice(0,num))
```

```js
let format = [3, 3, 1, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 13, 10, 3, 5, 5, 2, 2, 10];
let dates = [ "2021-10-04T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-05T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-06T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-13T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-14T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-15T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-15T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-17T22:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-18T22:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-19T22:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-20T22:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-21T22:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-17T22:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-18T22:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-19T22:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-20T22:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-19T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-20T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-21T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-22T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-19T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-20T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-21T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-25T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-26T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-27T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-28T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-29T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-25T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-26T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-27T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-28T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-29T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-01T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-02T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-03T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-04T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-05T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-08T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-09T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-10T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-01T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-02T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-03T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-04T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-05T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-08T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-09T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-10T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-11T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-12T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-11T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-12T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-13T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-15T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-16T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-17T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-18T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-19T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-16T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-17T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-18T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-19T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-20T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-23T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-24T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-23T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-24T04:00:00.000Z", "2022-01-05T04:00:00.000Z", "2022-01-06T04:00:00.000Z", "2022-01-07T04:00:00.000Z", "2022-01-10T04:00:00.000Z", "2022-01-11T04:00:00.000Z", "2022-01-12T04:00:00.000Z", "2022-01-13T04:00:00.000Z", "2022-01-14T04:00:00.000Z", "2022-01-17T04:00:00.000Z", "2022-01-18T04:00:00.000Z" ];

const res = format.map(num => {
  const arr = dates.splice(0,num)
  const start = arr.shift(); // take  the first
  const end = arr.length === 0 ? start : arr.pop(); // take the last if there
  return { start, end }
})
console.log(res)
```

To get an array of objects of start and end (you asked for only start if no end) you can do this - I am assuming the date strings are sorted. If not, you can easily sort the strings with `dates.sort()`

```
const res = format.map(num => {
  const arr = dates.splice(0, num)
  const start = arr.shift();
  const end = arr.length === 0 ? "" : arr.pop(); 
  return end ? { start, end } : { start }
})
console.log(res)
```

```js
let format = [3, 3, 1, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 13, 10, 3, 5, 5, 2, 2, 10];
let dates = [ "2021-10-04T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-05T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-06T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-13T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-14T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-15T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-15T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-17T22:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-18T22:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-19T22:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-20T22:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-21T22:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-17T22:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-18T22:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-19T22:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-20T22:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-19T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-20T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-21T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-22T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-19T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-20T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-21T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-25T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-26T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-27T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-28T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-29T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-25T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-26T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-27T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-28T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-10-29T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-01T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-02T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-03T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-04T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-05T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-08T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-09T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-10T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-01T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-02T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-03T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-04T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-05T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-08T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-09T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-10T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-11T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-12T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-11T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-12T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-13T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-15T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-16T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-17T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-18T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-19T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-16T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-17T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-18T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-19T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-20T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-23T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-24T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-23T04:00:00.000Z", "2021-11-24T04:00:00.000Z", "2022-01-05T04:00:00.000Z", "2022-01-06T04:00:00.000Z", "2022-01-07T04:00:00.000Z", "2022-01-10T04:00:00.000Z", "2022-01-11T04:00:00.000Z", "2022-01-12T04:00:00.000Z", "2022-01-13T04:00:00.000Z", "2022-01-14T04:00:00.000Z", "2022-01-17T04:00:00.000Z", "2022-01-18T04:00:00.000Z" ];

const res = format.map(num => {
  const arr = dates.splice(0, num)
  const start = arr.shift();
  const end = arr.length === 0 ? "" : arr.pop()
  return end ? { start, end } : { start }
})
console.log(res)
```

Or same start and end if only one date:

```
const res = format.map(num => {
  const arr = dates.splice(0, num)
  const start = arr.shift();
  const end = arr.length === 0 ? start : arr.pop(); 
  return { start, end }
})
console.log(res)
```

Comment: what is the benefit of flat map here?

Comment: thanks for the answer @mplungjan, that's definetely the "group of dates" that I want. But if I don't use map returning the start: and end: how I will get the expected output? Thanks

Comment: I mean my expected output is an array of objects, I think yours is an array of arrays

Comment: hey @mplungjan, I didn't noticed your answer. Yes, I want the first and last in each group as star and end, for single entries should be only start: and the date or start and end: with the same date. thanks

Comment: Don't worry @mplungjan, as it is now returning the same date on the end when there's only one date, should work.

Comment: @davs0ft I have coded both now

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan, it works awesome. But I'm wondering a small issue. The last object, starts: "2022-01-05T04:00:00.000Z" and ends: "2022-01-18T04:00:00.000Z". This group of dates should not be only one object, because there are unselected dates in the middle. It starts 05 and ends 18, but for example (08, 09, 15 and 16 are not selected dates), but actually we are counting them. What I though would happen when mapping, is we get object from 05 to 07, another from 10 to 14, and last from 17 to 18. Does this make sense for you? Thanks

Comment: So where does format come in? If you wanted to split the last into 3,5,2 why is that not in the format array instead of 10?

Comment: @mplungjan, because the format array it only counts the number of "group-dates" ignoring the start/end, and it comes from the server, I can't change that. Ideally that should come formatted in the "real" groups taking care of start and end dates.

Answer (score 0):

`Map` always return the same number of input as the output, so if you use dates you cant expect to get format array length output.
So we use the format as in input of the map to get array collection.

```js
let format = [3, 3, 1, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 13, 10, 3, 5, 5, 2, 2, 10];
let dates = [
  "2021-10-04T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-05T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-06T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-13T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-14T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-15T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-15T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-17T22:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-18T22:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-19T22:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-20T22:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-21T22:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-17T22:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-18T22:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-19T22:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-20T22:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-19T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-20T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-21T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-22T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-19T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-20T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-21T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-25T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-26T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-27T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-28T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-29T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-25T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-26T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-27T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-28T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-10-29T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-01T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-02T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-03T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-04T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-05T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-08T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-09T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-10T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-01T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-02T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-03T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-04T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-05T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-08T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-09T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-10T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-11T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-12T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-11T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-12T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-13T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-15T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-16T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-17T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-18T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-19T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-16T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-17T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-18T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-19T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-20T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-23T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-24T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-23T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2021-11-24T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2022-01-05T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2022-01-06T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2022-01-07T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2022-01-10T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2022-01-11T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2022-01-12T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2022-01-13T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2022-01-14T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2022-01-17T04:00:00.000Z",
  "2022-01-18T04:00:00.000Z"
];


// convert string into dates for comparison
const realDates = dates.map(d => new Date(d));

// use map on format since, map always return the same number of input array length, so that was ur clue to use format instead of dates 
const dateGroup = format.map(num => realDates.slice(0,num));

// now you only need to iterate over the array to return the new form
let app_multiple = dateGroup.map(function createNewObject(singleDateCollection, index) {

  return {
    start: new Date(Math.min.apply(null,singleDateCollection)),
    end: new Date(Math.max.apply(null,singleDateCollection))
  };
});
//
console.log(app_multiple);
```

Comment: That is a lot of maps

Comment: @mplungjan I could write it in two maps , but it would be hard to follow the intention of the code. I can also write it in single loop

Comment: Assuming the date strings are sorted then my second part seems simpler and quite readable

Comment: @mp if you take that assumption you can simply do it in one loop

Comment: As I  do. Otherwise I can sort before. Still only one loop